# Asking for 'email' permission as optional?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I want to start asking users of my app for their email address permission, so I have added email scope. I'm using the following code to authenticate my users:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    if(response.authResponse) {
        // Logged in
        doStuff();
    }else{
        // No session notification
        doNotDoStuff();
    }
}, {scope:'email'});
```

If a user declines the new permission, they cannot continue using the app. Is there any way to allow them to continue without it, or is this only permitted for permissions classified as 'extended'?

Comment: can't you ask for the `email` permission later, only once the users have logged in (to your application)? and, I don't know, use a cookie to remember if the user says no to the email permission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the new auth dialog this it's not possible to make `email` as optional permission, but nothing stops you from separating your auth flow from this permission requests (this may be a bit awkward however)...

You can leave auth flow for your application without asking for `email` permission and once authorized the user make an additional `FB.login` call specifying that permission. In that case it'll be up to user to decide if he want to share an email with your app without breaking the connection with app...